# Windows 7 Pinned taskbar items roaming profiles

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, roaming-profiles

I am using roaming profiles on a Windows server 2003 domain. On my Windows 7 box in the office i have have multiple items pinned to the taskbar.  however when i boot up offline (say at home) i don't get my pinned items.   is there a way to make these available offline?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to merge both your roaming and local profiles, to force them to update when making changes to the others.  You can do this via the users section of system -> control panel.  Or via system -> advanced system setting -> User Profiles.

Comment: Can you explain more thorough? I'm not sure I am able to "merge" my accounts.